# aws dynamodb java sdk: cannot resolve symbol 'standard': AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to use AWS DynamoDB Java API to create a `AmazonDynamoDBClient` object and get error

Following this example:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html

Using AWS DynamoDB SDK (Java): full `pom.xml` below

Code:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBclient = new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .build();
```

Error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'standard'

I am using Java 8, the IntelliJ IDE and Maven for build tool

My `pom.xml` (all dependencies latest version):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>A sample Hello World created for SAM CLI.</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/sdk-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.651</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My imports:

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.PutItemOutcome;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.spec.PutItemSpec;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with the S3 sdk that got resolved by updating all sdk versions to the latest in the dependencies Pom.xml. But now after those updates I get new errors about the DynamoDB call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()`, not `new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()`. Remove `new` keyword.